# PHP: clear a text file if it exceeds 50 lines

Tags: php

OK, what am I missing? I am trying to clear a file if it exceeds 50 lines.

This is what I have so far.

```
$file = 'idata.txt';
$lines = count file($file);
if ($lines > 50){
$fh = fopen( 'idata.txt', 'w' );
fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: `count file()` is invalid syntax...?!

Comment: try `count(file($file))`

Comment: Ditto on `brbcoding's` suggestion ;-)

Comment: @brbcoding, You should have posted as answer.

Comment: @Starx syntax errors like this should be deleted IMO... Not really a question that contributes anything to SO.

Comment: @brbcoding, Semantically correct but I think demoting such question will decrease a lot of participation on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = 'idata.txt';
$lines = count(file($file));
if ($lines > 50){
$fh = fopen( 'idata.txt', 'w' );
fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Too bad I don't get points for comments :P

Comment: @brbcoding Too bad we couldn't split/share the points. Call it a "joint venture" ;-)

Comment: YES that did it, I must be tried should have caught that. THANK YALL!

Comment: @ToxicMouse This way loads the file on the memory. Very risky way to solve the problem. Very large file will take long time to give `count(file($file))`

Answer (score 1):

If files really can be big you better loop:

```
$file="verylargefile.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
  if(linecount > 50)
  {
      break;
  }
}
```

Should do the job, and not the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of **count** is wrong.Replace this  line `count file($file);`  by

`count(file($file));`

Comment: This exact answer is right below you. Posted 5 minutes earlier.

Comment: The answer that was posted 5 minutes earlier just include the fixed code. Not even single word of explanation. Want to pin-point the exact error , that's why posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax, it should be `count(file($file));` Using this method is not recommended for larger file as it loads the file onto the memory. Thus, it will not be helpful in case of large files. Here is another way to solve this:

```
$file="idata.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  if($linecount > 50) {
      //if the file is more than 50
      fclosh($handle); //close the previous handle

      // YOUR CODE
      $handle = fopen( 'idata.txt', 'w' ); 
      fclose($handle);  
  }
  $linecount++;
}
```